# Count Most Vowel java

Tags: java

here is a logical error how can i find the most vowel sentence has the user entered .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ZanoreShqip {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fjalia;
        int count_zanore = 0;
        int maxVowelCount = 0;
        String wordWithMostVowels = "";
        final String SENTINEL = "FUND";
        System.out.print("Sheno fjali dhe fund per te perfunduar : ");
        fjalia=input.nextLine();
        while(!fjalia.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)) {
            fjalia = fjalia.toLowerCase();
            for(int i = 0; i <fjalia.length(); ++i) {
                char ch = fjalia.charAt(i);
                if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' 
                || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
                    count_zanore++;
                } if ( count_zanore > maxVowelCount) {
                    wordWithMostVowels = fjalia;
                    maxVowelCount = count_zanore;
                }
            }
            System.out.print("\nSheno fjali dhe fund per te perfunduar : ");
            fjalia = input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println(wordWithMostVowels);
        System.out.println(maxVowelCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What's the problem?

Comment: User has to type a bunch of sentences and i ve to find it which of them has more vowels

Comment: Yes, what's the problem? You posted code. What about it are you asking about?

Comment: Its wrong can u do it to show me how its done

Comment: Are you trying to count the word with the most vowels or the sentence with the most vowels?

Comment: iam trying to print the word who has most vowel and count how many vowels has

Comment: Can you add example inputs, what you expect the answer to be, and what you're getting instead?

Comment: this counter that i ve declaret count_vowels = 0;

Comment: he is counting all the vowels

Comment: iam trying to count the max vowels first by doing if ( count_vowels > max_vowels);  max_vowels = count_vowels

Answer (score 1):

You forgot this part `count_zanore = 0;`

Try this

```
while(!fjalia.equalsIgnoreCase(SENTINEL)){
   fjalia = fjalia.toLowerCase();
   for(int i = 0; i <fjalia.length(); ++i)
   {
      char ch = fjalia.charAt(i);
       if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i'
                    || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u'){
          count_zanore++;
       }
       if ( count_zanore > maxVowelCount){
                wordWithMostVowels = fjalia;
                maxVowelCount = count_zanore;

       }

   }
   count_zanore = 0;
   System.out.print("\nSheno fjali dhe fund per te perfunduar : ");
   fjalia = input.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Even the if condition can be moved outside the for loop. It does not serve any purpose within the for loop.

Comment: Its wrong again. it doesnt let me to SENTINEL this word Fund the loop is not ending

Comment: @CalvinIyer it is difficult for me to make him understand why I did it. Anyways this does it I believe.

Comment: @DrenBilalli make sure to verify this statement `final String SENTINEL = "FUND";`

Comment: The  final String is fine its just an logical erorr

Comment: @DrenBilalli post your code, let me check for an error